# java.sql.SQLException: Error reading from InputStream java.io.IOException

Tags: java, sql

i m using Struts2 for creating registration form , i want to store the image path in database and then want to retrieve the image in jsp. 
so in RegistrationService class i uses fileinput stream ,so that path get placed in database. 
but i get an error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Error reading from InputStream
>   java.io.IOException

RegistrationService.java

```
  FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(registration.getResume_attachment());
                            p.setBinaryStream(25,fis1,fis1.available());
                            FileOutputStream fos_resume=new FileOutputStream(registration.getResume_attachment());
                             byte buffer[]=new byte[1024];
                              int read=0;
                                       while((read=fis1.read(buffer, 0, 1024))!=-1){
                                          fos_resume.write(buffer);
                                          }
                                       fis1.close();
                            fos_resume.close();
```

Registration.java

```
 public class Registration{
        private   String resume_attachment;
          private String photo_attachment;
           private   String pre_company;
//getter and setter
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: @sufiyan the resume_attachment should be File type not String type :) http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/